# Generic class with reference to itself

Tags: swift, generics

I have the following classes in Swift:

```
class A {}; class B {}

class Collection<T> {
    var parent: Collection?
}
```

When I want to build a hierarchy like

```
var rootCol = Collection<A>()
var childCol = Collection<B>()
childCol.parent = rootCol
```

The last line produces this error:

`Cannot assign value of type 'Collection<A>' to type 'Collection<B>?'`

What type does `parent` have to be, so that one can assign it with different generic types?

Comment: You'll want to make [a type eraser](http://robnapier.net/erasure).

Comment: Unrelated, but you probably shouldn't use the name `Collection` for your type, as it's already the name of a standard library protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to assign an instance of type `Collection<A>` to a variable of type `Collection<B>?` which is not possible , You can only assign `Collection<A>` to `Collection<A>` or `Collection<B>` to `Collection<B>`.
Although your aren't writing `<T>` at the end of the parent type but swift infers that to be of the type `Collection<T>` and then also optional.
In This case I would recommend using protocol.

One more thing,it's advisable to NOT use names for classes that conflict with swift protocols.

```
class A {}
class B {}

protocol Foo{}

class Bar<T>:Foo {
    var parent: Foo?
}

var rootCol = Bar<A>()
var childCol = Bar<B>()
childCol.parent = rootCol
```

Comment: Of course, this relies on the fact that you will be the sole user of this code and can specify that `Bar` is the only type conforming to `Foo`. If someone else comes along and creates a class conforming to `Foo`, it will no longer be the case that the parent of a `Bar` must also be a `Bar`.

Comment: That defeats the reason of having a generic class. E.g. when you have a `func get() -> T` in `Bar`, it won't be accessible as `child.parent.get()` and you cant add it to `Foo` since type `T` is not known there.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure can either be a tree of "containers" using a generic class based on the contained data (which can work on both reference and value types).

For example:

```
class TreeOf<T>
{
   var value:T?               = nil
   weak var parent:TreeOf<T>? = nil
   var children:[TreeOf<T>]   = []

   init(_ value:T? = nil)
   { self.value = value }

   func addChild(_ value:T) -> TreeOf<T>
   { 
      let newNode = TreeOf<T>()
      newNode.value = value
      children.append(newNode)
      return newNode 
   } 
}

var directory = TreeOf<String>("/")

directory.addChild("usr")
directory.addChild("library")
let users = directory.addChild("users")
users.addChild("paul")
users.addChild("John")
users.addChild("Mary")

let userNames = directory.children[2].children.map{$0.value}
```

Or your tree nodes themselves (i.e. the objects that are linked in the tree structure) can implement the linking variables and use a common protocol to obtain all the tree manipulation functionality for free. This however, only works on reference types and requires a final class.

For example:

```
protocol TreeNode:class 
{
   var parent    :Self?         { get set }
   var children  :[Self]        { get set }
}   

extension TreeNode 
{   
   func removeFromParent()
   { 
     parent?.children = parent!.children.filter{$0 !== self}
     parent = nil 
   }

   func childOf(_ newParent:Self) -> Self  
   { 
     removeFromParent()
     parent = newParent
     newParent.children.append(self)
     return self 
   }

   // ... more generic tree related functions provided by protocol for all classes
   // e.g. root, count descendants, searches, traversal, prune and graft, etc.
}

final class FamilyMember:TreeNode
{
   var parent:FamilyMember?    = nil
   var children:[FamilyMember] = [] 

   var name = ""
   init(_ newName:String) {name = newName} 
}

let paul  = FamilyMember("Paul")
let mary  = FamilyMember("Mary").childOf(paul)
let john  = FamilyMember("John").childOf(paul)
let suzie = FamilyMember("Suzie").childOf(mary)
let luke  = FamilyMember("Luke").childOf(mary)
let irene = FamilyMember("Irene").childOf(john)

let miniPaul = paul.children.map{$0.name}
let miniMary = mary.children.map{$0.name}
```